# Cannot connect to Oracle db in play 2.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have been trying since many days to connect to Oracle database using Play 2.4 framework, but all my attempts are in vain. So, seeking some solution for this. 
I have tried the following configurations in `application.conf`, but none worked:

```
db.default.driver=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
db.default.username=user_name
db.default.password=password

1) db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:host_port:sid"
2) db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin://@host_name:host_port/sid"
3) db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin://host_name:host_port/sid"
4) db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:host_port:sid"
   db.default.host=host_name
5) db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin://@host_name:host_port/sid"
   db.default.host=host_name
6) db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin://host_name:host_port/sid"
   db.default.host=host_name
```

Below is the exception which I am getting in every case:

> ```
> CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:
>
> 1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
>       while locating play.api.db.DBApiProvider
>       while locating play.api.db.DBApi
>       for field at play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider.dbApi(DBModule.scala:80)
>       while locating play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider
> at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
> at play.api.db.DBModule$$anonfun$namedDatabaseBindings$1.apply(DBModule.scala:34):
>    Binding(interface play.api.db.Database qualified with
>       QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to
>       ProviderTarget(play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider@5968e9a8)) 
>       (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
> Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
>     at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178)
>     at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829)
>     at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
>     at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>     at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
>     at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
>     at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for looking at my questions but finally referring to online posts and play 2.4 documentations, below is the answer to this issue:

```
  a) Url format for oracle will be as below:
     db.default.url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host_name:host_port:sid"
  b) Add property as:
     db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
     # above query will be used to check connection, this is required.
```

Thanks,
Pradeep Sharma